# Postgresql An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have postgresql 9.1.19 deployed on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

For some reason, it started throwing exceptions with no other information other than "an I/O error occurred while sending to the backend".

It only happens with certain tables.

If I use a clean database, the error disappears, which leads me to believe I am running out of memory or some other allocated resource which is causing the error??

I'm connecting via JDBC.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was performing an IN query with too many parameters...due to an ORM generated query.

But very unhelpful message that could've been much more specific.

For example, Postgres will throw a more helpful message if you select too many columns, or use too many characters, etc.  Maybe this is a jdbc issue too, not sure.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to debug / trace it?

Answer (score 1):

The error means you're timing out while connecting to the database.

Check you have the connection configured correctly. If it is, see if you have access to the database or there's some firewall forbidding the access.

Comment: the db is on the same server, and the rest of the app works fine.  so i can connect, but for some reason, on one particular table, this exception is being thrown.  Also, timeouts usually result in a hang of some sort, but this exception happens immediately.  I just wish there was more information about what is happening...very useless exception that in my experience can mean alot of different things.

Comment: Can you perform the exact same query on the database without using your app to confirm is the query?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.   This is occuring when spring batch loads all the data, a million records, and it persists them without issue, but after that its trying to update the metadata tables and then this error is thrown.  Do you have any recommendation  as a fix?